# multiplying DecimalFormat number (no longer rounded properly)

Tags: java, numbers, decimal, decimalformat

I'm basically trying to use DecimalFormat to get to two decimal places. I'm taking two integer values then dividing them and casting to a double I've put in sample values below. When I do as below I get a value that is no longer to two decimal places. It seems to be when multiply by the 3 it loses it's rounding.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
double d = Double.parseDouble(df.format((double)5/6))*3;
System.out.println(d);
```

Can you let me know why this occurs and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statemet:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(df.format((double)5/6))*3;
```

the formatting is not preserved (Double returns a double).

You could do, e.g.:

```
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Comment: Thanks a mill  Svea  - yeah calling the format method from within the println works.